# Laravel Mail::Send() Infinitely retries and breaks Amazon SES

Tags: laravel, email, amazon-web-services

I'm using Laravel Mail::Send() and Mail::Queue() function with amazon SES.

I'm getting a weird error when I send any email with queue (after 3 tries):

> Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found in
>   /..../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/Parser/PayloadParserTrait.php:39

But, I still get the 3 emails.. and it shows in my failed_jobs table as failed because of this error.

Now when a user does something that uses Mail::Send(), its really bad: it keeps retrying and sending forever, amazon SES putz a ton of emails on their queue and keeps sending emails the entire day. (Last time I got 20k emails sent to my mailbox)

My question is: how to limit the number of tries when using Mail::Send() and what can I do about this error?

Note: I don't know if it relates on not, but this started happening after I switched to PHP7

Comment: Do you have php-xml extension installed?

Comment: I do, yes. I installed php7.0-xml, it shows on phpinfo() but error remains